# Lambda calling update_item, error: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: +, operand type: M

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using a lambda function to work with a dynamodb table. The function is written in python, and I just used the one from an aws tutorial (this is for a personal project to learn AWS). It's working great for "read" (get_item) and "create" (put_item), but "update" (update_item) is throwing this error, and I can't figure out why. I'm using a test query I built with NoSQL Workbench. When I hit "run" for the same query in Workbench, it works, and it also works when I call it from the command line. Whenever I go through the lambda function it throws this error, but like I said, the function works fine for the other calls.

The lambda code:

```
import boto3
import json


def handler(event, context):
    '''Provide an event that contains the following keys:

      - operation: one of the operations in the operations dict below
      - tableName: required for operations that interact with DynamoDB
      - payload: a parameter to pass to the operation being performed
    '''

    operation = event['operation']

    if 'tableName' in event:
        dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table(event['tableName'])

    operationsDict = {
        'create': lambda x: dynamo.put_item(**x),
        'read': lambda x: dynamo.get_item(**x),
        'update': lambda x: dynamo.update_item(**x),
        'delete': lambda x: dynamo.delete_item(**x),
        'list': lambda x: dynamo.scan(**x),
        'echo': lambda x: x,
        'ping': lambda x: 'pong'
    }

    if operation in operationsDict:
        return operationsDict[operation](event.get('payload'))
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unrecognized operation "{}"'.format(operation))
```

The test query:

```
{
  "operation": "update",
  "tableName": "CCDynamoDB",
  "payload": {
    "Key": {
            "id": {"S":"visitorCount"}
        },
        "UpdateExpression": "SET #7c680 = #7c680 + :7c680",
        "ExpressionAttributeNames": {"#7c680":"currentCount"},
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":7c680": {"N":"1"}}
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your payload. Try like below. For better understanding, suggesting you to take a look at this [document](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html).

```
CCDynamoDB.update_item(
    Key={
        'id': 'visitorCount'
    },
    UpdateExpression='SET currentCount = :val1',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':val1': 1
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Subhashis! I was playing around with put_item and made a mistake that I believe explains what was going on. For anyone else reading, I believe the problem was: 

By setting "ExpressionAttributeValues": { ":val1": {"N": "1"}} I was mapping :val1 to { "N": "1" } instead of setting it to 1. 

The resulting schema in the Item field of the DynamoDB table would have looked like this:
"currentCount": {
    "M": {
      "N": {
        "N": "1"
      }
    }
  }

Instead of this:
"currentCount": {
    "N": "1"
  }

Please correct me if I'm wrong, hope it helps.

Comment: The working query takes the "N" out, and the "S" as well. In addition to using the Workbench query, I had been trying to follow the syntax at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html. @Subhashis's source is clearer.

Comment: The working payload, in the same syntax as the original post:

"payload": {
    "Key": {
            "id": "visitorCount"}
        },
        "UpdateExpression": "SET #7c680 = #7c680 + :7c680",
        "ExpressionAttributeNames": {"#7c680":"currentCount"},
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":7c680": "1"}
  }

edit: tried and failed to format code like a regular post